# D365- Virtual Entity - Lookup is not able to filter while Typing the values

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have created a custom Connector(Plugin) for retrieving data.
We have a lookup of virtual entity in case and while searching data in lookup, We are not getting the filter condition in plugin.From advance find we can get the filter condition In InputParameter[Query]. Please let me know if anyone has any idea to get the lookup filter condition (while searching) in plugin.

Comment: Any luck with the resolutions? We are facing the same issue, have filter in Advanced Find, but not in the lookup.